# Windows 7 giving RAM to installed graphics-card

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, upgrade

Just installed Windows 7 Ultimate. Sorry but I haven't installed any program that could tell my specs, but I remember theses:

```
Graphics Card: ATI Radeon HD 4650 1GB GDDR2 AGP with support of DirectX 10.1
RAM: Kingston 1 stick 1GB
CPU: Intel Pentium 4 2800 mhz
Installed DirectX 11
```

Sorry for russian text but you will understand that Windows is giving 251MB of RAM to video card. How to disable this feature because system running out of RAM?

[image: ATI RADEON HD 4650]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows that the memory will be shared, but it doesn't give any memory until & unless the GPU runs out of memory.  You can't disable this, and neither does it being enabled make any difference - till your GPU loads such large textures that it runs out of memory

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot  disable the shared memory, still you can reduce the amount of share. You can do this through the BIOS of your motherboard.You can reduce this to as low as 128 MB depending upon the board.

Also your system is running out of RAM because of windows7's requirements in both graphics as well as system processes. Still RAM increase upto 3GB for Windows 7 in recomended for optimum performance.